# How do I extract and use tags from a rss feed in XCode?

Tags: html, xcode, ios5, rss, tags

I'm in need of some help today and my question is how do I go about extracting imgs tags and other possible tags from a RSS feed,  I've searched google and I did find something using NSScanner but it doesn't explain how to use it in my code.

After extracting the tags I also want to use the text in a table cell.

How do I go about doing this?

I'm a beginner at xcode so I'm not sure how to adapt code unless it's written clearly.

I should also state this is for a iOS project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than re-invent the wheel, you could try incorporating a 3rd party library for reading RSS feeds.  I've used [MWFeedParser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/) in a project with great success.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I'll let you know if I need more help with this.